# Filtering records in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I want to select records from **suppliermsg**  table which have latest **MsgDate** with in 2 months from today.

How to change the following for that.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM suppliermsg";
```

Comment: Did you try to Google for this issue? [mysql between dates](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mysql+where+date+condition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dUvdVeTULMqy0AS386joCQ#q=mysql+between+dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DATE_ADD() or DATE_SUB() for comparison. This will show you everything from past two months.

```
SELECT * FROM suppliermsg WHERE MsgDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

Comment: Nice, except question said "with in 2 months from today", which means 2 months into the future. You likely did what was intended, but not what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM suppliermsg
where MsgDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND MsgDate>CURDATE();